# add parameter in url using .htaaccess

Tags: .htaccess

This is my url www.testsite.com and i need to add this parameter looking like  www.testsite.com/?camp=20 , i have try this code but it is not work.

```
RewriteEngine on


RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^testsite.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.testsite.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

Comment: Consider removing "php" tag and adding more relevant ones, like mod_rewrite, htaccess or apache

Comment: @Mayur: What are you trying to do and what is the problem?